# Text is out of the window

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a header menu where some menus are on the left side on some of them on the right side.

Here's the html of the header:

```
<li class="nav6">
    <a href="#img"><img src="example.com/img.png"></a>
</li>
<div class="options">
    <li class="nav5">
        <a href="1">1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav5">
        <a href="2" target="_blank">2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav5">
        <a href="3">3</a>
    </li>
</div>
```

And here's the css:

```
.nav6 {
   position:absolute;
   left:95%;
}
.nav6 a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:black;
}
.nav5 a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
.nav5 {
    float:right;
}
.nav5 a {
    display: block;
    color: #282828;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;

}

.options {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;;
}
li{
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

So the problem is that either I'm on the phone or I'm just making the window smaller, part of the image that is in the *.nav6* is partly going out of it or, because on my site I've added an automatic scroll bar, it automatically shows a scroll bar.

The thing I want is that the image would be on the right side, the *.options* would be on the left as they are but, the image would be fully seen in every way.

I've tried to add to the *.nav6* a style:

```
float:right;
```

But the problem is that I've gotten a drop down menu in the *.nav6* and it doesn't open with that style.

Comment: Media queries should be use for responsive website

Comment: Have you considered using flex?

Comment: @LuísP.A. What?

Comment: why do u use `li` without `ul`???

Comment: @לבנימלכה I use ul , Didn't put it here.. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the `image` in `right` side you have to put the options before `.nav6`
and warp all with div and set `display:flex`

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/om7am3x5/

```css
.warp{
  display:flex;
}
.nav6 {

}
.nav6 a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:black;
}
.nav5 a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
.nav5 {
    float:right;
}
.nav5 a {
    display: block;
    color: #282828;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;

}

.options {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;;
}
li{
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<div class=warp>
<div class="options">
    <li class="nav5">
        <a href="1">1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav5">
        <a href="2" target="_blank">2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav5">
        <a href="3">3</a>
    </li>
</div>
<li class="nav6">
    <a href="#img"><img src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba1.jpg"/></a>
</li>

</div>
```

Comment: tell me for more help

Comment: happy to help...you can use `.nav6 img{
    width: 95%;
}` to set width to img